# Change status when I click in the child of an element (+AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### The goal

Change status when I click in the child (`<i>`) of an element (`<li>`)

### The problem

Nothing happens when I click in `<i>`, that is child of `<li>`.

### Details

I'm using AngularJS with `ng-click`. See:

```
<li ng-click="openNavigator($event)">
    <i class="ico ico-home"></i>
</li>
```

### Update

Guys, you are right — it's working! The problem, actually, is a little bit further.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXxLs/). If you click exactly on the button, the console retrieves back to you a specific result; otherwise, if you click exactly on the icon, you get another response from `$event.target`.

This behavior isn't good for me — it's flimsy. In my real application **I need to** work with parents, siblings, etc. and that incosistence unleashes expected, but unwanted, results.

Can  you all see my problem? If so, ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the angular version ? because with angularjs/1.2.3 it works

Comment: This should work.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/7NgJf5mYVuT81yK78nzG?p=preview.

Comment: When you say `change status` what exactly do u mean?

Comment: Which ones the button and which ones the icon? I'm a lil confused

Comment: Ha! I see what u mean. Sometimes the target gives you the `li` and sometimes the `i`. Which one do you need exacty?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Which one do you need exactly?

Comment: I need `<li>` — I think it's more concise.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge check update below

Comment: Any luck? @GuilhermeOderdenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='currentApp' ng-controller='ACtrl'>
    <li class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-phone" ng-click="openNavigator($event)"></i>
    </li>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
currentApp.controller('ACtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $event) {
    $scope.openNavigator = function($event) {
        var target = $event.target['parentElement' || 'patentNode'];
        console.log('li parent', target);
    }
}]);
```

Since the `i` tag is a child of the `li` and the click event is inconsistent, then I suggest you target the `i` tag on click and then grab the parent. You can say it's the bubbling down, which is correct, So to fix it target the `i` and it won't bubble up.

The main reason this is an issue is because AngularJS doesn't have event delegation functionality like jQuery does, so you can't specifically target the `li` tag.

The fiddles been updated too!

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n53yr/7/)**

Comment: Take a look in my updated question, please. We are almost there!

Comment: Unfortunately, no success for us. [Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/jaJ8W/) — same thing as before. By the way, thanks by now.

Comment: Your ng-click is on the li, it's should be on the i tag. @GuilhermeOderdenge. Check my solution

Comment: I already checked. I forked on your example. The point is: if you put in the `i` tag, we lost the click on `li`.

Comment: But then you can move back up the DOM and grab get it's parent, the `li`

Comment: I tried this, @dcodesmith. Have you checked the last jsFiddle that I posted?

Comment: Yup but your jsfiddle has the ng-click on the `li` not the `i`. @GuilhermeOderdenge

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand. If I try to put `ng-click` on the `i`, I just get some result if I click right in the icon; otherwise, nothing happens. Try it yourself (with your own example if you wish).

Comment: Ok! @GuilhermeOderdenge. I did some CSS trickery so the `i` tag the exact same size as the `li` so now wherever you click on the button you'll hit the spot. Check the fiddle on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNpxNO?p=preview)